# Code assist for scala in eclipse throws up errors

Tags: eclipse, scala, runtimeexception, code-assist

I'm a few hours old in scala.
I use eclipse , and i went to the market place and installed the scala ide plugin for eclipse. Now when i do ctrl+space , i get two pop-up error warnings , and only after closing both , i get to the usual code support dropdown.

Below are the two pop-ups , does anyone have a solution to this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could be a conflict with another plugin or any number of other issues. I would recommend just downloading a fresh bundle from here and trying again: http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html

Comment: Ok . I'm re-downloading it. I assume installing this one will automatically replace the old one ? (I'v always installed stuff through eclipse marketplace , so not sure)

Comment: Just unzip it somewhere like `C\:` and it will be  independent of your other eclipse installations.